# How to check routes on template?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

Does anyone know how to check if a template is being accessed through a url route with the django template language?

Here is my situation: There's this template `article.html`, that shows all posts of a blog when accessed through `blog-home` url route, and that also shows only posts of a given user through `user-posts` url route.

This template works like that because what defines which posts will be shown are the classes in views.py.

That being said, here is what I tried to do: (*I know its wrong*)

```
{% if url == 'user-posts' %}
  "Some HTML h1 tag I want do be shown only when this template is accessed via 'user-posts' url"
{% endif %}
```

How would be the correct way, if there's any, to write this *if* statement?

Comment: You would usually pass something in the context for each view that the template would use to change it's output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Django matches a url pattern a [`ResolverMatch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch) object is created and made available on the request object at `request.resolver_match`. This `ResolverMatch` object can be queried in your template to acheive what you want, the [`url_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch.url_name) attribute is the name of the url pattern that was matched

```
{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'user-posts' %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was precisely what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a [custom templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/),

**my_app/templatetags/utils.py**

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def is_active_view(context, *view_names):
    request = context.get('request')
    for view_name in view_names:
        if getattr(request.resolver_match, 'view_name', False) and request.resolver_match.view_name == view_name:
            return True
    return ''
```

And use it in your template this way, assuming `blog-home` is the url name you gave to your url :

**blog-home.html**

```html
{% load utils %}

{% is_active_view 'blog-home' as display_blog_home_section %}

{% if display_blog_home_section %}
<!-- Your code -->

{% endif %}
```

NB : this template tag can check after multiple view names at once and support namespaced url :

```html
{% is_active_view 'front:blog-home' 'front:blog-categories' as display %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Although it is not a straight forward solution to my use case, your answer will be very useful to other functionalities I'm planning to my application.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer to give you an even more complete example (such as checking against multiple views)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more optimized version of this if you are using boostrap and trying to make the menu options "active" when you are on that URL

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def is_active_tab(context, *view_names):
    request = context.get('request')
    for view_name in view_names:
        if getattr(request.resolver_match, 'view_name', '') == view_name:
            return 'active'
    return ''
```

And you use it like

```
                    <li class="nav-item {% is_active_tab 'games:list' %}">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'games:list' %}">
                            {% translate "My Quizzes" %}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item {% is_active_tab 'games:create' %}">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'games:create' %}">
                            {% translate "New Game" %}
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

It adds an extra `active` classname to the class of the element if any of the view_names match the current view name.  Makes the template writing much cleaner